# No-socket alternative to tmux or screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, tmux, sockets, afs

My university gives each student a directory on their AFS which is accessible via SSH. There is a (light) CLI-driven piece of software that I would like to run continuously from the university.

I thought I could just run the software through screen via SSH, detach, then reattach from any other SSH session whenever it's CLI needed to be accessed. However, screen and tmux do not work since they depend on sockets for their functionality and sockets cannot be created on AFS space. ( see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=676663 )

My account is unprivileged but has access to a toolchain that can be used to compile and run things locally.

Is there a good solution to this?

Comment: Don't know what AFS is, but can you simply force the app to run in the background with a trailing &

Comment: The application's CLI would not be accessible if you used &.

Comment: Right, that wasn't clear.

Comment: Noted. I've edited and clarified the question

Answer (score 4):

The link you posted indicates that a newer version of `screen` does not use your home directory, but a directory under `/var`, which probably is not AFS-mounted. You could install that version if need be. Likewise, `tmux` uses `/tmp` by default.

You can choose an alternate, non-AFS directory for the socket in `screen` (via the `SCREENDIR` environment variable) and in `tmux` (via the `-S` option, which takes a socket name, not just a directory, as its argument).